# JQuery scripts are not loading on my website

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this code, and I want to hide a div clicking on a  tag
I was using some jQuery scripts to do that, but I don't know why, the scripts aren't loading.

Code:

```
<body>
         <div class="myprojects">
             <a href="">my projects</a>
         </div>

         <br>

         <div class="links">
             <a href="https://domain.gq" target="_blank">domain.gq</a>
             <br>
             <a href="https://domain.art" target="_blank">domain.art</a>
         </div>

         <div class="contactme">
             <a href="mailto:adress@domain.me">contact me</a>
         </div>
         
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

         <script>
             $('#links').hide();
         </script>

         <script>
             $(document).ready(function(){
                     $("#myprojects").click(function(){
                         $("#links").fadeToggle();
                     });
             });
         </script>
         
     </body>
```

I want people to click on "my projects" and then, the links div to show up, but scripts aren't loading.

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have selector issues in several places. e.g:

You used the id selector

```
$('#links').hide();
```

You should use the class selector:

```
$('.links').hide();
```

Same issue with `#myprojects`, it should be `.myprojects` the class selector.

BTW, why not put the hide logic inside the `$(document).ready` method?

```html
<div class="links">
  <a href="https://domain.gq" target="_blank">domain.gq</a>
  <br>
  <a href="https://domain.art" target="_blank">domain.art</a>
</div>

<div class="contactme">
  <a href="mailto:adress@domain.me">contact me</a>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<script>


</script>

<script>

$(function() {
  $('.links').hide();
    $(".myprojects").click(function() {
      $(".links").fadeToggle();
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: The author's logic is just placed in `$(document).ready`.

Comment: Yeah, putting the `$('.links').hide();` action in `$(document).ready` would ensure the element is loaded first before the hide function is done on it.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Please see first script tag used by the author.

Comment: @huan feng, oh, I didn't notice this script tag. sorry

Comment: `$(document).ready` is actually deprecated in favor of the shortcut approach `$(function(){` which as the docs state is preferred now. As for the $('.links') not inside it... as long as the script tag is after the elements can get away without using the ready

Comment: Same selector problem with `$("#links").fadeToggle();` also

Comment: @charlietfl Updated. Thanks for the comments.